# Routing priority, module routes before default? - Pingpong Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my default routes I've got some routes like:

```
Route::get('modules/{module_slug}', 'Backend\ModuleController@getModule');
```

The module_slug parameter will come from the database, but I also have some specific modules with routes like:

```
Route::get('modules/pages', 'PagesController@index');
```

For the modules I use **Pingpong** a laravel package that gives a module structure to the application like:

```
- app
-- Http
--- routes.php
-- Other Folders
- modules
-- Pages
--- Http
---- routes.php
```

How can I make sure that the route from the module is taken if a module in the database happens to be pages as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution. In the default RouteServiceProvider include the routes before the default routes. Do this with a loop through the modules folder.

If pingpong use include or require once these files will not be include twice.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel Routes are evaluated in the order they appear in the routes.php file.

If you place your module routes above the routes you are building from your database, they will always take precedence.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm sorry maybe my question wasn't clear enough.  I'm using pingpong package. My routes are in different files. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You really can't be sure about it. I'd suggest creating the slugs with more than 5 letters. And be sure to keep the `'modules/pages'` route before the `'modules/{module_slug}'`